# How best can i link product_id to images so the one product can have multiple images linked

Tags: laravel

Iam working on eCommerce website. i have products which iam uploading fine with 1 display image. i want to have multiple images uploaded separetly in a different table but linked by product_id to identify images belonging to this product

here is my database schema

```
    Schema::create('product_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('product_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('size');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('product_id')
              ->references('id')->on('products')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

with this iam able to upload images fine but when i check my database, there is no foreign key linking to products captured when uploading these images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a One To Many relationship on your product.

Here's an example.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductImage');
    }
}
```

Next, you need to define the inverse of the relationship in `App\ProductImage`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductImage extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

You could then retrieve all images associated with a product by doing something like this:

```
$images = App\Product::find(1)->images;
```

When creating a new `Product`, you could also associate `ProductImage` with it directly by doing the following:

```
$product->images()->createMany([
    ['path' => 'path-to-file.jpg',],
    ['path' => 'path-to-file.jpg',],
]);
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your response. i have defined the relationships just fine. but what i need assistance on is how to get the product_id when saving images to database. here is my store function in ProductImage controller `if($request->hasFile('file')) {
 foreach ($request->file as $file) {
 $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
 $filesize = $file->getClientSize();
 $file->storeAs('public/images',$filename);
 $productImage = new ProductImage();
 $productImage->name = $filename;
 $productImage->size = $filesize;
 $productImage->save();
  }
}` .hope its clear. dont know to format

Comment: Your question is not very clear. How you get the `product_id` is totally up to you. For example, It could be a hidden input in your form that also gets submitted in the request.

Comment: Thanks alot. appreciate it so very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel Elequent. Use One To Many Relationship. A one-to-many relationship defines as a Single model owns multiple models

[One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Else you can join these two tables by using laravel query builder

[Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins)

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you If you are using laravel Elequent use One To Many (Polymorphic)
you can see doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations)